# How to list all the datasets availabe in the datasets R package using an R command?

Tags: r, dataset

I'd like to retrieve the list of all the datasets in the datasets R package in a vector in R. Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This how I thought to do it:

```
search() ## find attached packages
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
ls(pos=6)
```

but the docs for `ls` say `pos` is "there for back compatibility".

```
ls(name="package:datasets")
```

or

```
library(help="datasets")
```

(which also gives a short description of each data set)